# Want to use PostgreSQL db and ST_AsMVT() to develop a tile server, assuming my start point is a GeoTIFF

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geotiff-tiff, vector-tiles

So basically I want to use ST_AsMVT() function to generate a web server that generates vectors tiles for me, which can then can be accessed through a link like "http://localhost:8080/{z}/{x}/{y}.mvt". The GeoTIFF in consideration is drone mapped RGB image for certain section in a place.
[image: a section of the TIFF viewed in QGIS]

Here is what I do know:

- I need to use the PostGIS to give me the appropriate table that will
  allow me to use ST_AsMVT()
- I have a basic understanding of raster2pgsql enables to us to get raster tiles from a TIFF and store the data into my db. Would this allow me to work with the data? i was able generate raster tiles for this map in QGIS

The references I used to research this:

- This article
  https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/dynamic-vector-tiles-from-postgis
  which had links to git repos that had demos of a working webserver
  (e.g. https://github.com/urbica/martin) as I described but I am still
  confused on how to exactly process my TIFF file to arrive at useable
  table which then can used by one of the services(demos) mentioned in
  the article
- for raster2pgsql https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vAQk9kG3YH4

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Your Question doesn't really have a question in it, just a large task, vaguely described. We're a problem-solving site, for use when you run into something deep in the weeds towards solving a task, and of less use when you're starting to brainstorm on options for implementing something.

Comment: What makes you think you need *vector* tile support, to serve *image* tiles? Use e.g. GeoServer, or search for WMS/WMTS server implementations (and tile creation) on GitHub.

Comment: @geozelot i just thought that is what is standard now (instead of raster tiles), also i want to use deck.gl to represent some data on top of this maps

Comment: It is informal standard to serve *vector data*, which used to be rasterized to image tiles to serve before the advent of vector tiles. But you have *raster data*, which is much better served as image tiles! deck.gl will happily render images onto a base mesh, and with your complement vector data on top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So with the help of @geozelot i was able to conclude the following:

1. I cannot use vector tiles for my geoTIFF as it is raster data
2. To accomplish my initial goal generating a tile server for raster data
   i can use Geoserver's TMS(tile mapping service) or python's
   Terracotta
   (https://terracotta-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)